# Differences between ruby ffi module and the fiddle module

Tags: ruby, ffi, ruby-ffi

Except the fact that Fiddle is a module from the standard library of ruby and that ruby-ffi is an external module, what are the main differences between them.

More specificaly, what could be the reasons that lead you to use one over the other? (except the fact that one create a dependancy to an external gem).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Basically `ruby-ffi` is dead and not maintained any more, so just go with Fiddle.

**Update:** Seems that `ruby-ffi` is still alive, so it can be used as well as the `Fiddle` module.

Comment: ruby-ffi is maintained at all. This is wrong answer. See https://github.com/ffi/ffi/commits/master.

Comment: Oh, yes, that seems to be true, I believe it stuck with migration to ruby 2.0 a couple years ago.